# Errback in Scrapy for spider does not fire

Tags: python, scrapy

The below code does not call the errback: error_handler. What could be the problem? It does however reach parse_listings and throw an exception that is caught by scrapy and logged.

```py
import scrapy

class ListingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listings'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://www.google.com/",
            callback=self.parse_listings,
            errback=self.error_handler,
        )

    def parse_listings(self, response, **request_kwargs):
        raise TimeoutError

    def error_handler(self, failure):
        self.logger.error("DOES NOT REACH HERE")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5438 . errback is used for errors during request handling such as connection errors, NOT during processing of the response.